# Code enters function before data arrives - How to make it wait for all data before continuing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I subcribed to the observable and then put the data in an array(array_item). In the second foreach() I iterate through the array to get my data but it never executed because the array was still empty. I mean the execution moved on to this foreach() while I'm yet to recieve all my data. How can I make it wait till all the datas are recieved and in the array before continuing to the 2nd foreach() and manipulating the array (array_item) items.

```
names: any[] = [];
array_item: any[] = [];
drawtimeline(nom_cal, _hitoService, idcalbuscador) {
  this.names.forEach((ev) => {
    groups.add([{id: ev._id, content: ev.nom_calendario, cal_id: ev._id}]);
    var g = ev._id;


    for (var i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
      this._hitoService.getHitos(this.names[i]._id)
          .subscribe(hito1 => {
            this.hito1 = hito1
            this.array_item.push(hito1);
          });
    }

    console.log("before 2nd foreac()");
    for (var j = 1; j < this.array_item.length; j++) {
      console.log("inside 2nd foreac()");
      this.array_item[j].forEach((item) => {
        console.log("i =  " + i + " id_item: " + this.calendarObject._id + " j =" + j);
        items.add([{
          id: i,
          group: g,
          start: item.start_datetime,
          end: item.end_datetime,
          style: itemStyle(item.design),
          className: "pepe"
        }]);
        console.log("i =  " + i + "id_item: " + this.calendarObject._id);
      });
    }

  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';`

```js
names: any[] = [];
array_item: any[] = [];
drawtimeline(nom_cal, _hitoService, idcalbuscador) {
  this.names.forEach((ev) => {
    groups.add([{
      id: ev._id,
      content: ev.nom_calendario,
      cal_id: ev._id
    }]);
    var g = ev._id;

    Observable.forkJoin(this.names.map(v => {

      return this._hitoService.getHitos(v._id)
        .map(hito1 => {
          this.hito1 = hito1;
          this.array_item.push(hito1);
        })
    })).subscribe(res => {

      console.log("before 2nd foreac()");
      for (var j = 1; j < this.array_item.length; j++) {
        console.log("inside 2nd foreac()");
        this.array_item[j].forEach((item) => {
          console.log("i =  " + i + " id_item: " + this.calendarObject._id + " j =" + j);
          items.add([{
            id: i,
            group: g,
            start: item.start_datetime,
            end: item.end_datetime,
            style: itemStyle(item.design),
            className: "pepe"
          }]);
          console.log("i =  " + i + "id_item: " + this.calendarObject._id);
        });
      }

    });
  })
}
```

Comment: it never printed the `console.log("before 2nd foreac()");` before the last for(), meaning it never iterated over the array.

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu I'm working on it all the time. Check it right now, remember to import `Observable`.

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu There was a little error which I've already fixed. And I'm not 100% sure if the `return` keyword is really needed there, just right under the `Observable`.

Comment: I managed to get just one item, the last for() only iterated once (j=1). then it threw up this error `TypeError: log is null`.

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu Can you show me what `console.log` says? Which logs are being sent to the console?

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu There must be something wrong with `console.log`s. If you could try to delete them all and check if any errors will be thrown into console?

Comment: posted a dropbox link to see the screenshot of the console error

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu I think that there's an error because there's nothing like `i`. If you could try to `for (var j = 1, i = 0; j < this.array_item.length; j++, i++) {}`. Tell me if it change anything.

Comment: cheers! I manage to modify the code to get some of the data, but your code helped alot

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu That's great to hear, my dear friend! I'm very glad. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Any code that is dependent on an asynchronous process, must only be called after the asynchronous process has completed. To wait for all responses, you can use forkJoin: [RxJS Observable.forkJoin](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_methods/forkjoin.html)

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

const requests = Observable.forkJoin(this.names.map(name => this._hitoService.getHitos(name._id)));
requests.subscribe(responses => { <do stuff with responses here> });
```

responses will be an array of the responses from each call to _hitoService.getHitos

Comment: I'm afraid that you will call that second `for` loop as many times, as the `this.names.length` is.

Comment: I was able to get just one item! .. then it threw this error: `TypeError: log is null`

Comment: Revised, but the answer is a little bit more generic, to try and not get caught up with the details. Observable.forkJoin() is probably what you want to be using.

Comment: @mwalt in `.... observable.forkJoin(this.names.map(name =>this._hitoService.getHitos(name._id)));` does the cod `this.name.map` takes all the values in my names[ ] and makes serveral petition... can't figure that out.

Comment: Array.prototype.map applies a function to every element in the array, returning a new array. E.g.,

`[1,2,3,4].map(el => el + 1) // [2,3,4,5]`

The map in the example takes each name and returns the call to getHitos